# Text/HTML editor in jsFiddler.NET

Tags: javascript, html, html-editor, jsfiddle

I was curious what is the Text editor [jsFiddle.NET](http://jsfiddle.net/) is using (for HTML, Stylesheet and  script parts).

It seems to be very light with lots of cool keyboard features.

I tried to inspect its source but couldn't find a particular name in resources.

Any idea of what is the name of the editor? and its license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From EditorCM.js:

```
/*
 Class: MooshellEditor
 Editor using CodeMirror
 http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/index.html
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Code mirror
    http://codemirror.net/